# VS2019 Linux C++: undefined reference "dlopen", g++ -ldl compiler flag not applied

Tags: c++, linux, g++, cross-compiling, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a remote C++ build from VS2019 to an Ubuntu target machine. I need to load dynamic libraries inside the code so I include  and invoke the dlopen and dlsym functions inside the source. For this to work I apparently need to pass the option -ldl to g++ which I do in Property Pages C/C++->All options->Additional Options. Is this the right place to add this? I do not see another more reasonable place where I can add to g++ command arguments. This does not work when sending the build from VS2019 but if I move the same source to Linux and compile there directly using g++ with the same flag it builds no problem. I assume the -ldl option never makes it across from VS2019 to Linux. How can I set this properly or custom modify the command line arguments that get sent to g++?

Comment: `-ldl` is a linker option, not a compiler option. So you might have more luck with Property Pages->Linker->All options->Additional Options

Comment: Tried that also but does not work either

Comment: According to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/prop-pages/linker-linux?view=vs-2019 you should set Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

Comment: Amazing! That did the trick! I have been looking for this for hours. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of a Linux project is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=vs-2019

The linker properties are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/prop-pages/linker-linux?view=vs-2019

See property "Library Dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me: set Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies (enter -ldl in this field).